# Showing hidden input field with custom text

Tags: javascript, html, input, textfield, visibility

I have this text field hidden with HTML hidden code, now when the user enter an invalid input I use javascript to unhide the text field and display an error message, this is what is suppose to happen.

I have seen a lot of css style like

```
`style.visibility = 'visible';` and `style.display='block';`
```

But none of them are working for me what happens is that the error text shows for less than a second and then disappears, any one would like to share their thoughts.

This is the complete code for better understanding, it's still not working in firefox and Edge while IE and Chrome wont do anything, in Firefox, it just blinks once on each button press and that about it.

Javascript:

```
</script>
function validate(){
var firstname = document.getElementById("fn").value;

if (firstname == "") {
    document.getElementById("fn").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("fn").text = "ERROR";
}
}

function init()
{
    var formData = document.getElementById("enqForm");
    formData.onsubmit = validate;
}

window.onload = init;
</script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="enqForm">
    <input id="fn" type="text" placeholder="First Name *" />
    <input id="sendbutton" type="submit" value="Enquire" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is `validate()` called? Where is the user entering anything? Post a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: You can't show a hidden input. Change the type to `text` and make it invisible, and show whenever you want

Comment: HTML spec: "The [hidden] input element represents a value that is not intended to be examined or manipulated by the user"

Comment: @ j0869 : Validate is called via form.onSubmit, the user is not entering any string, the field is hidden and ought to become visible to show error in input in a different field that is just aboe this field, this field will only show error

@Arnau Lacambra : type was changed to text and then was made to display, NOT WORKING.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the style, you *can* change the form's `type` attribute.

Using JavaScript - assuming you want to change `lnspan` to `text`:

```
document.getElementById('lnspan').type = 'text';
```

Style is not the same as the `type` attribute.
Also there's two `id` attributes in your `<input>`, you may want to change that.

Answer (score 0):

```
**THAT IS THE ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION**
<html>
<head>
<script>
function newDoc() {
document.getElementById("hid").type="text";
document.getElementById("hid").value="ERROR";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Load new document" onclick="newDoc()">
<input type="hidden" id="hid" value="">

</body>
</html>
<!--However this makes your error message as text field which is not good.
What you can do is make the Error into embedded into paragraph <p> so the  
 users cannot change it and it also looks more professional    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function newDoc() {
document.getElementById("te").innerHTML="ERROR";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Load new document" onclick="newDoc()">
<p id="te">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The answer looks big but it's pretty simple if you understand it

Comment: Not working, there were 2 issues faced, 1 is the visibility of the field, that became visible for less than a second, 2nd was the text to display, as I understand the text will be displayed when the field is visible, again, the field shows for less than a second and disappear and then text shws but since the field is invisible the text disappears as well